# Need to display streaming video occupying the fullscreen

Tags: android

I am using **VideoView component for streaming video in Android** , but the streaming video is **occupying only a part of the screen of the mobile device both in portrait/landscape mode**.

Kindly provide the code to so that the **streaming video is displayed covering the full screen in portrait/landscape mode.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible, AFAIK. Videos are shown in their original aspect ratio, as big as the screen can handle. What you are asking for is for Android to change the video's aspect ratio.

Comment: Will overriding the onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) function of the VideoView help to solve the issue ?